# How to link libraries containing lib and include folders in cmake on windows

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, linker, sfml

This is my basic file structure:

```
├── BUILD
│   └── lib
│       └── *.a files
│   └── include
│       └── library
├── test.cpp
└── CmakeLists.txt
```

I'm trying to link boh the include and lib folder files to `test.cpp`.  This is my current CmakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_executable(test test.cpp)

target_include_directories(test PUBLIC ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/BUILD/include)

target_link_libraries(test not-sure-what-to-put-here)
```

I know my `target_include_directories` line is working however no matter what i put for `target_link_libraries` it seems to always fail and give the error:

```
undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf6StringC1EPKcRKSt6locale'
undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf9VideoModeC1Ejjj'
undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf12RenderWindowC1ENS_9VideoModeERKNS_6StringEjRKNS_15ContextSettingsE'
undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf12RenderWindowD1Ev'
```

I was hoping to get help on what I'm doing wrong with my `CMakeLists.txt` file, thank you!

*Edit 1, this is for statically linked libraries*

Comment: So do I need to include every .a file in the lib folder then?

Comment: ***So do I need to include every .a file in the lib folder then?*** Not the libraries that have finder modules and are supported by CMake. I don't know what your .a files are for. If they are SFML its well supported. My first link describes the proper way.

Comment: "This is probably what you want since you tagged sfml: https://github.com/SFML/SFML/wiki/Tutorial%3A-Build-your-SFML-project-with-CMake" Sadly, that tutorial is outdated

Comment: I am sorry, follow the link to the forum post for a better solution: [https://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=24070.0](https://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=24070.0)

Answer (score 1):

You tagged your question with the `sfml` tag, so you got comments and an answer about this library. However it looks like your question is only about some static libraries you want to link to your executable. This should work:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_executable(test test.cpp)

target_include_directories(test PUBLIC ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/BUILD/include)

target_link_libraries(test ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/BUILD/lib/libA.a ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/BUILD/lib/libB.a)
```

So, yes - you need to list all the libraries in the `target_link_libraries` command.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using dynamic/shared SFML use this.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

target_include_directories(test PUBLIC ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/BUILD/include)

add_library(sfml-graphics shared IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET sfml-graphics PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/BUILDv/lib/libsfml-graphics.so)
add_library(sfml-window shared IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET sfml-window PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/BUILD/lib/libsfml-window.so)
add_library(sfml-audio shared IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET sfml-audio PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/BUILD/lib/libsfml-audio.so)
add_library(sfml-network shared IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET sfml-network PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/BUILD/lib/libsfml-network.so)
add_library(sfml-system shared IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET sfml-system PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/BUILD/lib/libsfml-system.so)

add_executable(test test.cpp)


target_link_libraries(test sfml-graphics sfml-window sfml-audio sfml-network sfml-system)
```

If you are using a static version of sfml use this.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

target_include_directories(test PUBLIC ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/BUILD/include)

add_library(sfml-graphics-s shared IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET sfml-graphics-s PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/BUILDv/lib/libsfml-graphics-s.a)
add_library(sfml-window-s shared IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET sfml-window-s PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/BUILD/lib/libsfml-window-s.a)
add_library(sfml-audio-s shared IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET sfml-audio-s PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/BUILD/lib/libsfml-audio-s.a)
add_library(sfml-network-s shared IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET sfml-network-s PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/BUILD/lib/libsfml-network-s.a)
add_library(sfml-system-s shared IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET sfml-system-s PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/BUILD/lib/libsfml-system-s.a)

add_executable(test test.cpp)

target_link_libraries(test sfml-graphics-s sfml-window-s sfml-audio-s sfml-network-s sfml-system-s freetype X11 Xrandr pthread GL GLU udev FLAC ogg vorbis vorbisenc vorbisfile openal)
```

this should definetly work